# Netbeans: text color for user defined types

Tags: c++, xcode, netbeans, colors

I'm using Netbeans to work on a C++ project under Linux.
I noticed that Netbeans colors with the same color all the identifiers!
I would like to distinguish colors for this two groups:

- Variable identifier (such as local variable)
- User types (user defined struct and/or class)

Xcode works as I want:

[image: Xcode colors]

You can see in "main" that color of "AwesomeClass" type is different
from "localVariable" identifier.

This is as NetBeans appears instead:

[image: NetBeans colors]

No color distinction between type "AwesomeClass" and variable identifier "localVariable".

I spent hours trying to change this behavior without results! :-(

Is this possible with Netbeans?
If no, can someone suggest me a free C++ IDE for linux with a better syntax coloring?

Thanks!

EDIT: Eclipse works like Xcode, but I would like to know if this is also possible with Netbeans!

Comment: How is this question about programming?  As I see it this is just about how to configure the syntax highlighting in your chosen IDE/Editor - not really a good question for SO.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I see various similar questions on this site...